# How can I add the Print option to the Share menu?

Tags: android, android-intent

See [this short video](https://streamable.com/dy6xc8). In the pre-installed Files app, I can press access a Print option through the Share menu. But if I try this from my own app, Print is not one of the options. How can I add this functionality to my own app?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to use

```
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
```

instead of

```
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
```